# Linker error LNK2005

Tags: c++, linker, lnk2005

I'm trying to compile my app with a static library and I got these error:

```
3>LIBCMT.lib(stdexcpt.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::bad_cast::bad_cast(char const *)" (??0bad_cast@std@@QAE@PBD@Z) already defined in QuestLoaderLib.lib(QuestLoader.obj)
3>LIBCMT.lib(stdexcpt.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::bad_cast::~bad_cast(void)" (??1bad_cast@std@@UAE@XZ) already defined in QuestLoaderLib.lib(QuestLoader.obj)
3>LIBCMT.lib(stdexcpt.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::bad_cast::bad_cast(class std::bad_cast const &)" (??0bad_cast@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z) already defined in QuestLoaderLib.lib(QuestLoader.obj)
3>QuestLoaderLib.lib(QuestLoader.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall std::ios_base::Init::Init(void)" (??0Init@ios_base@std@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _$E14
3>QuestLoaderLib.lib(QuestLoader.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall std::ios_base::Init::~Init(void)" (??1Init@ios_base@std@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _$E15
3>QuestLoaderLib.lib(QuestLoader.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall std::locale::_Iscloc(void)const " (?_Iscloc@locale@std@@QBE_NXZ) referenced in function "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)" (??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@H@Z)
3>QuestLoaderLib.lib(QuestLoader.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::locale::facet const * __thiscall std::locale::_Getfacet(unsigned int,bool)const " (?_Getfacet@locale@std@@QBEPBVfacet@12@I_N@Z) referenced in function "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)" (??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@H@Z)
3>QuestLoaderLib.lib(QuestLoader.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl std::_Xlen(void)" (?_Xlen@std@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "protected: virtual class std::ostreambuf_iterator<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > __thiscall std::num_put<char,class std::ostreambuf_iterator<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(class std::ostreambuf_iterator<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >,class std::ios_base &,char,bool)const " (?do_put@?$num_put@DV?$ostreambuf_iterator@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@std@@MBE?AV?$ostreambuf_iterator@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@2@V32@AAVios_base@2@D_N@Z)
3>QuestLoaderLib.lib(QuestLoader.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl std::_Xran(void)" (?_Xran@std@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::assign(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?assign@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAEAAV12@ABV12@II@Z)
```

Both my app and QuestLoaderLib.lib are compiled with /MT option. How to fix this?

Comment: Are both compiled with the same Character Set settings?

Comment: Yes, all compiles with "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" option.